# Generate WSDL button for Apex class without webservice method

Tags: soap, wsdl

I have an Apex class which is actually a wrapper class, and has multiple properties which are marked with the keyword "webservice". This class is used for an inbound integration over SOAP. There is a separate Apex class that has the provided services, i.e, the webservice methods in it, which actually makes use of the above wrapper.

However I see that the wrapper class has a "Generate WSDL" button on it from UI.
When I hit that button, I do get a WSDL, which however doesn't include the inner classes or the properties of this wrapper. I get the complextypes Address and Location defined (I have no idea why just these and nothing else).

Can anyone explain what is the purpose of having this "Generate WSDL" button available on an Apex class that doesn't even have any webservice method? From the docs it seems this button only makes sense where we have a webservice method. (pic from the docs below)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer helps? [Custom Webservice class design](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/261971/4726)

Comment: @Raul sorry but no, actually the question you linked is trying to solve a problem which is already working for me. In my code, like the end solution of the other question, I already have different wrappers outside my webservice facade class. The consumer party has generated a WSDL using the button on my wrapper class (not the facade), and that generated WSDL doesn't have the properties. They want to know why. I simply told them they are to generate using the button on the facade and not the wrapper. Still, was curious as to the purpose of the button on the wrapper, hence the question I posted.